# ruby interpreter: when is a variable defined?

Tags: ruby

I noticed a pretty odd behaviour in a ruby irb console. If I execute:

```
irb(main):001:0> defined?(a)
=> nil    
irb(main):002:0> a = true if defined?(a)
=> true
irb(main):003:0> a
=> true
```

since I haven't defined `a` and `defined?(a)` returns `false` I would expect `a = true` to not be executed. But that's not the case and `a = true` is actually executed and `a` has value `true`.

This can be simplified to

```
irb(main):001:0> a = "hello" if false
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> defined?(a)
=> "local-variable"
```

What I thought at the beginning is that `a` is defined before checking the condition but converting this into:

```
irb(main):001:0> (a = "hello") if false
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> defined?(a)
=> "local-variable"
```

Who can explain this behaviour to me? How does ruby evaluate such statement?

```
if false
  a = "hello"
end

defined?(a) # true
```

Comment: In this line you use `a` as an instance variable, so it's no longer undefined. You can read this article for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48623161/weird-behaviour-of-defined-in-ruby

Comment: You linked the same question :)

Comment: Of course, I meant: http://seejohncode.com/2013/11/10/ruby-local-variables-are-undefined/

Answer (score 3):

It has nothing to do with `defined?`. It seems the parser needs to define that variable in advance if there's a chance it needs that. Check this

```
a
NameError (undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object
a = 4 if false
nil
a
nil
```